# Debounce in sfx react

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, react, office-ui-fabric-react, react-webpart

The code I am using:

```
<TextField onChanged={e => this.handleCommChange(e, 'Contact')}

private handleCommChange(e: any, controlType: any): void {
    const { temp_items } = this.state;
    const value = e;

    this.setState({
      temp_items: {
        ...temp_items,
        [controlType]: value
      }
    });
    //console.log(controlType);
    console.log(this.state);
}
```

I Want to implement debounce in SPFx web part created using react js.

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: This question shows a lack of research and doesn't refer to any existing documentation like https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#debounce

Comment: If it is in jquery ... I may not ask the question . As I am new es6 & spfx so I asked the question . If you can give me documentation of SPFX React (debounce) I will thank full .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could leverage [lodash debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#debounce) and wrap your method's body as the debounce parameter (callback)

Comment: than you . But I am in spfx react .. does this work ? please suggest .

Comment: Yes, you just need to add the lodash library

Comment: ok. Than you. I will try.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer :)